# Why does truffle console work fine with testrpc but truffle serve isn't finding accounts?

Tags: truffle

I'm running testrpc on the default port 8545.

I run `truffle console` and test with: `web3.eth.sign(web3.eth.accounts[0], web3.sha3("123"))`

This works fine. According to docs the sign method only works if the account is unlocked, so it seems I should be all set.

But after successfully running `init/compile/migrate`, I run `truffle serve` and when I go to the web page on localhost:8080, I get this popup message:

"Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly."

Comment: Are you doing both `truffle serve` and opening the browser on the same machine?

Comment: Yes, same machine :)

Comment: What does your Truffle configuration look like?

Comment: v2.0.0 on Ubuntu, node v5.12.0

Comment: Just a standard install

Answer (score 3):

I got this error as well.

I had MetaMask Ethereum client installed but had not logged in yet.

The default truffle app.js picked up the web3 instance injected by MetaMask.  Once I logged into MetaMask to create initial accounts, the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

If Metamask plugin added to your chrome and you are using chrome then your code uses Web3 instance injected in Metamask. Once you login/unlock the Metamask then your code will get account address which created by Metamask.If you need TestRPC's default account address i.e account[0] then try with other browser.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error too and the solution was a variation of @modpy 's one.

So I had tried to upgrade the MetaMask Chrome plugin and it was in the process of doing that - So MetaMask was enabled and was trying to connect to the local blockchain on port 8545.

Removing MetaMask from Chrome did the trick (and later I re-installed the upgraded version)